# Add content after the first post in WP Loop

Tags: php, loop

I want to display a list of categories after the **first post** in the Loop of index.php (this is the template my WP theme uses to display posts).

I've searched around on the web and found some code (see below) which is supposed to do as I want - inject a list of category titles as links between a list of posts in the Loop.

However, it is not working as expected. It only shows one category title, not all of them.  Interestingly, it displays the title of the first post's category, but no others.

My Loop code, including the custom code I inserted, is as follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('content'); ?>

<div>

<?php 
 if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) { 

   $categories = get_the_category();
   $separator = ' ';
   $output = '';
   if($categories){
     foreach($categories as $category) {
       $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
     }
     echo trim($output, $separator);
   }
} 

?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hoping someone can help.

Thanks,

Mekong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_category()` retrieves the current post categories. To get all categories you should use `get_categories()` instead

Comment: Yes, that worked! Many thanks, much appreciated!